# Binding a class property to a Checkbox using C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have an application that allows a user to load multiple text files consisting of data points. Upon loading these files, there is a Node with checkboxes enabled generated for each. Then each file selected becomes an instance of a "DynoFile" class, all of which are stored in list. Is there a way that I can bind the Node's checkbox to it's particular instance of the "DynoFile" class (The node and the instance of the DynoFile class share the same name)? My previous method was to run through all of the checkboxes, and compare the names of those that are checked to the names of the DynoFile instances in my list. I feel like there must be a way to have the checkbox event alter a parameter in the corresponding DynoFile class.

Below is my code thus far.

```
  List<DynoFile> AllRuns = new List<DynoFile>();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode RunGroup = new TreeNode();
        RunGroup.Text = GroupName.Text;
        RunGroup.Name = GroupName.Text;
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(RunGroup);

        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        dlg.FilterIndex = 0;
        dlg.Multiselect = true;
        dlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
        dlg.Title = "Read .txt Log File";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            BuildTree(RunGroup,dlg.FileNames);
            BuildRuns(GroupName.Text, dlg.FileNames);
        }
    } // Load the File names into an array

    public void BuildTree(TreeNode RunGroup, String[] FileNames)
    {
        foreach (String file in FileNames)
        {
            TreeNode run = new TreeNode();
            run.Name = Path.GetFileName(file);
            run.Text = Path.GetFileName(file);
            RunGroup.Nodes.Add(run);
        }
    } // Parse the array and construct the tree of nodes

    public void BuildRuns(String GroupName, String[] FileNames)
    {
        foreach (String file in FileNames)
        {
            DynoFile element = new DynoFile(Path.GetFileName(file), GroupName);
            AllRuns.Add(element);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this Using the "OnDataBinding" method on the checkBox. When creating your checkboxes give the an unique ID that will let them to be recognized  in order to know to what node / DynoFile you are reffering (like the id of the node position).
I could help you further more if you gave me the code that is actually comparing the names

Comment: Well, currently I essentially have two ForEach loops, the outer cycled through the nodes and tests for the check condition, and the inner (which is triggered if the box is checked) cycles through the names of the DynoFile classes finding it's matching checkbox

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'll use a repeater in the page to display the checkboxes, see this webSite :
http://www.sitepoint.com/asp-net-repeater-control/

The source of your Repeater can be a list of Object that contains the name of the node and the name of the file.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="catlist" runat="server" DataSourceId="ListOfNodeNameAndFile">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <CheckBox isChecked='<%# Container.NodeName == Container.FileName%>'/>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Let me know !

Comment: This should be moved to the similar question of ASP.NET  :)